# feedback panel push nav aside

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a feedback panel but the problem is that when you click on it the navigation overrides some contents of the feedback panel.

[image: a busy cat]

As you can see in the image above the email input field is blocked.

**Question**

What I want to do is that when a user clicks on the feedback, the `<nav>` will float to the left so that the user can enter what they want and then they click on `feedback` again and the `nav` returns back to `center`.

Comment: Try to type with proper grammar, correct spelling, and more semantic words so that anyone who would like to answer you can understand what you are saying/asking without having to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Ilan Biala thanks English is my 7th language

Comment: If you can post your HTML and some more CSS I'll take a look at it.

Comment: just have your click event toggle a class on the nav that adds the float rule or whatever other rules you want to implement

Comment: You don't have a `nav` element in the HTML...?

Comment: @IlanBiala html 5 `nav` element look it up.

Comment: I know what the `nav` element is, but you don't have one in your code and your code is gone now...